# Light reflects change the material

Tags: javascript, graphics, 3d, three.js, light

I have a basic scene with a ground and a unique light. But where the light its the mesh it produce a strange effects. The shadows are casted without any problem, but all the others meshes affected by the light produce a weird effect.

[Here is a Online demo.](https://jotask.github.io/AdvanceCompuerGraphics/)

And here is a screenshoot that what is going on:
[image]
[image]

The black square on the ground and the black lights are produced by the light.

Comment: These look like numerical problems. Show some code. Do you have near and far clipping plane set up reasonably?

Answer (score 1):

That artifact looks like what is known as "shadow acne".
It is a common problem of shadow mapping.
Just a little modification is needed in the shader that takes care of shadow mapping.

You can find a very well written guide on shadow mapping [here](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-16-shadow-mapping/#result---shadow-acne).
Basically there are two solutions explained there:

1. Render the shadow map using the back faces.
2. Add a bias to the test that determines if a fragment is occluded.

Of course in order to do this you would need to have access to the fragment shaders.